# Custom IDE-compatible static-types in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-internals

For the sake of nicer design and OOP, I would like to create a custom IDE-compatible static type. For instance, consider the following idealized class:

```
class IntOrIntString(Union[int, str]):

    @staticmethod
    def is_int_string(item):
        try:
            int(item)
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        # I know __instacecheck__ is declared in the metaclass. It's written here for the sake of the argument.
        return isinstance(instance, int) or (isinstance(instance, str) and self.is_int_string(instance))

    @staticmethod
    def as_integer(item):
        return int(item)
```

Now, this is a silly class, I know, but it serves as a simple example. Defining such class has the following advantages:

1. It allows for static type-checking in the IDE (e.g. `def parse(s: IntOrIntString): ...`).
2. It allows dynamic type-checking (e.g. `isinstance(item, IntOrIntString)`).
3. It can be used to better encapsulate type-related static functions (e.g. `inetger = IntOrIntString.as_integer(item)`).

However, this code won't run because `Union[int, str]` can not be subclassed - I get:

> TypeError: Cannot subclass typing.Union

So, I tried to work-around this by creating this "type" by referring to it as an instance of `Union` (which it actually is). Meaning:

```
IntOrIntString = Union[int, str]
IntOrIntString.as_integer = lambda item: int(item)
...
```

but that didn't work either as I get the error message

> AttributeError: '_Union' object has no attribute 'as_integer'

Any thoughts on how that could be accomplished, or, perhaps, justifications for why it shouldn't be possible to accomplish?

I use python 3.6, but that's not set in stone because I could change the version if needed. The IDE I use is PyCharm.

Thanks

**Edit:** Two more possible examples for where this is useful:

1. The type `AnyNumber` that can accept any number that I wish. Maybe starting with `float` and `int`, but can be extended to support any number-like type I want such as int-strings, or single-item iterables. Such extension is immediately system-wide, which is a huge bonus. As an example, consider the function

```py
def func(n: AnyNumber):
    n = AnyNumber.get_as_float()
    # The rest of the function is implemented just for float.
    ...
```

2. Working with `pandas`, you can usually perform similar operations on `Series`, `DataFrame` and `Index`, so suppose that there's a "type-class" like above called `SeriesContainer` that simplifies the usage - allows me to handle all the data-types uniformly by invoking `SeriesContainer.as_series_collection(...)`, or `SeriesContainer.as_data_frame(...)` depending on the usage.

Comment: Can you please try to clarify in regular typing jargon what you are trying to achieve? The examples are by construction non-sensical. For example, a type such as `IntOrIntString` would be either a union of int/string or have the additional method - since int and str don't have the method. The `AnyNumber` conflicts with the [number pyramid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) - for example, complex is a number but cannot uniquely be represented as a float. Are you looking for typeclasses or traits, perhaps? Did you consider ABCs, singledispatch, or the third party multipledispatch?

Comment: Don't get lost in the details. I could instead use `AnyNumber.get_complex`, or `AnyNumber.get_quaternion` if I'd like. I could just as well use `AnyRealNumber` with `get_float`. All common thing among the above examples is that they match functionality not to a type, but to an aspect of the type (not unlike using python abstracts like `Mapping` or `Iterable`. In all the above cases, I can easily write code for a "standardized" form of the data, but support many other types in an extensible way.

Comment: As some of the answers and comments correctly show - I can easily separate the three "advantages" I give above: I could use `Union[Int, String]` for static type-checking, `intStr_isinstance()` for dynamic type-checking and `intStr_get_number()` for standardization. My question is, however, about combining all three into the same class.

Comment: This appears to be a very complex requirement you are requesting. Providing an answer will involve some work. Please provide a *clear* problem description so people do not waste their time finding out later on which details are important and which are not. To re-iterate, the current requirements cannot be met consistently. For example, ``a: IntOrIntString`` would allow both ``a = 3`` (since ``IntOrIntString`` is a ``Union[int, str]``), and ``a.as_integer(a)`` (since ``IntOrIntString`` defines ``as_integer``). Which is wrong, as there is no such thing as ``(3).as_integer("12")``, for example.

Comment: Your are correct in that there's no `(3).as_integer()`. However, as the code is written, it is not meant to be used like that since this is a static function

Comment: As the code is written, using this staticmethod is *explicitly allowed*. Hence, please clarify your requirement with an example that does not contradict itself, or abstractly describe what functionality is desired.

Comment: Point taken. Will do.

Answer (score 2):

if I were you I would avoid creating such classes since they create unnecessary type ambiguity. Instead, to take your example, in order to achieve the objective of differentiating between a regular string and an int string, this is how I would go about it. First, make a (non static) intString class:

```
from typing import Union
class intString(object):
    def __init__(self, item: str):
        try:
            int(item)
        except ValueError:
            print("error message")
            exit(1)
        self.val = item

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.val)
```

(It might be better to inherit from str, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly and it's not material to the issue).

Lets say we have the following three variables:

```
regular_string = "3"
int_string = intString(regular_string)
int_literal = 3
```

Now we can use the built in python tools to achieve our three objectives:

1. static type checking:

```
def foo(f: Union[int, intString]):
    pass

foo(regular_string)      # Warning
foo(3)                   # No warnings
foo(int_string)          # No warnings
```

You will notice that here we have stricter type checking then what you were proposing - even though the first string can be cast into an intString, the IDE will recognize that it isn't one before runtime and warn you.

2. Dynamic type checking:

```
print(isinstance(regular_string, (intString, int)))  # <<False
print(isinstance(int_string, (intString, int)))      # <<True
print(isinstance(int_literal, (intString, int)))     # <<True
```

Notice that isinstance returns true if *any* of the items in the tuple match any of its parent classes or its own class.

3. I'm not sure that I understood how this relates to encapsulation honestly. But since we defined the **int** operator in the IntString class, we have polymorphism with ints as desired:

```
for i in [intString("4"), 5, intString("77"), "5"]:
    print(int(i))
```

will print 4,5,77 as expected.

I'm sorry if I got too hung up on this specific example, but I just found it hard to imagine a situation where merging different types like this would be useful, since I believe that the three advantages you brought up can be achieved in a more pythonic manner.

I suggest you take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype for more basic functionality relating to defining new types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not quite what I was looking for. This would be useful  in cases where someone would like to extend support of different argument types throughout the system. For example, suppose a function accepts a type `AnyNumber` which supports anything from one-item lists to complex numbers, then this support is simpler by using `AnyNumber.get_as_float()`. `AnyNumber` is then easily extensible to more types. The relation to OOP is the encapsulation of the relevant functions within `AnyNumber`, and not in some external function `AnyNumber__get_as_float()`.

Comment: BTW, if you wish to inherit from `str`, you should usually inherit `collections.UserString`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple thoughts. First, `Union[int, str]` includes all strings, even strings like "9.3" and "cat", which don't look like an `int`.

If you're okay with this, you could do something like the following:

```
intStr = Union[int, str]

isinstance(5, intStr.__args__) # True
isinstance(5.3, intStr.__args__) # False
isinstance("5.3", intStr.__args__) # True
isinstance("howdy", intStr.__args__) # True
```

Note that when using a `Union` type, or a type with an origin of `Union`, you have to use `.__args__` for `isinstance()` to work, as `isinstance()` doesn't work with straight up `Union`s. It can't differentiate `Union`s from generic types.

I'm assuming, though, that `intStr` shouldn't include all strings, but only a subset of strings. In this case, why not separate the type-checking methods from the type hinting?

```
def intStr_check(x):
    "checks if x is an instance of intStr"
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return True
    elif isinstance(x, str):
        try:
            x = int(x)
            return True
        except:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Then simply use that function in place of `isinstance()` when checking if the type is an `intStr`.

Note that your original method had an error, being that `int(3.14)` does not throw an error and would have passed your check.

Now that we've gotten `isinstance()` out of the way, if for parsing purposes you need to differentiate `intStr` objects from `Union[int,str]` objects, you could use the `NewType` from `typing` like so:

```
from typing import NewType

IntStr = NewType("IntStr", Union[int,str])

def some_func(a: IntStr):
    if intStr_check(a):
        return int(a) + 1
    else:
        raise ValueError("Argument must be an intStr (an int or string of an int)")


some_num = IntStr("9")

print(some_func(some_num)) # 10
```

There's no need to create an `as_integer()` function or method, as it's exactly the same as `int()`, which is more concise and readable.

---

*My opinion on style*: nothing should be done simply for the sake of OOP. Sure, sometimes you need to store state and update parameters, but in cases where that's unnecessary, I believe OOP tends to lead to more verbose code, and potentially more headaches maintaining mutable state and avoiding unintended side effects. Hence, I prefer to declare new classes only when necessary.

---

**EDIT**: Since you insist on reusing the function name `isinstance`, you can overwrite `isinstance` to add additional functionality like so:

```
from typing import NewType, Union, _GenericAlias

isinstance_original = isinstance

def intStr_check(x):
    "checks if x is an instance of intStr"
    if isinstance_original(x, int):
        return True
    elif isinstance_original(x, str):
        try:
            x = int(x)
            return True
        except:
            return False
    else:
        return False

def isinstance(x, t):
    if (t == 'IntStr'): # run intStr_check
        return intStr_check(x)
    elif (type(t) == _GenericAlias): # check Union types
        try:
            check = False
            for i in t.__args__:
                check = check or isinstance_original(x,i)
                if check == True: break
            return check
        except:
            return isinstance_original(x,t)
    else: # regular isinstance
        return isinstance_original(x, t)

# Some tests
assert isinstance("4", 'IntStr') == True
assert isinstance("4.2", 'IntStr') == False
assert isinstance("4h", 'IntStr') == False
assert isinstance(4, 'IntStr') == True
assert isinstance(4.2, int) == False
assert isinstance(4, int) == True
assert isinstance("4", int) == False
assert isinstance("4", str) == True
assert isinstance(4, Union[str,int]) == True
assert isinstance(4, Union[str,float]) == False
```

Just be careful not to run `isinstance_original = isinstance` multiple times.

You could still use `IntStr = NewType("IntStr", Union[int,str])` for static type checking, but since you're in love with OOP, you could also do something like the following:

```
class IntStr:
    "an integer or a string of an integer"
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        if not (isinstance(self.value, 'IntStr')):
            raise ValueError(f"could not convert {type(self.value)} to IntStr (an int or string of int): {self.value}")

    def check(self):
        return isinstance(self.value, 'IntStr')

    def as_integer(self):
        return int(self.value)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.value

# Some tests
try:
    a = IntStr("4.2")
except ValueError:
    print("it works")

a = IntStr("4")

print(f"a == {a()}")

assert a.as_integer() + 1 == 5
assert isinstance(a, IntStr) == True
assert isinstance(a(), str) == True
assert a.check() == True

a.value = 4.2

assert a.check() == False
```

Comment: You too are too hung-up on this specific example - this is hardly what I'm going for. Read the example I commented on @mattan's answer. However, you gave me some ideas I could try and use. Thanks for that. Also, the "sake of the OOP" is that I will not declare `IntStr = NewType("IntStr", Union[int,str])`, and then have to use `intStr_check` every time, but rather encapsulate this functionality in the same place - just use `IntStr.check`, fior example, or better - `isinstance(x, IntStr)`.

Comment: Perhaps you could include more examples to clarify your question? Your specific example can and probably should be done without OOP, in my opinion, given that all that goes into the type system in Python is a bit of a mess. Perhaps you might be more interested in working with a language such as Julia?

Comment: I suppose if you wanted everything in the same place you could make a modified version of `isinstance()`, but with a different name, and just have it use the regular `isinstance()` method whenever you test against something other than `'IntStr'`

Comment: Moving to Julia is not an option for now. I included more examples in the original question. Regarding modifying `isinstance`, I'd rather plug-into existing syntax/implementation rather than rewrite all my to use `my_isinstance`.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty because your answer is slightly better than the other one (sorry @mattan) and I'd hate seeing the rep go to waste, but it still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @EZLearner I've updated my answer to meet all of your requirements